# adding my value of my dynamic row to my DB

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

I have a problem : my coworker played with my code and now it doesn't work anymore. Have any idea ? Here is my code, I checked it twice but can't see what changes were made and why it doesn't work

```
<?php
// Connect to the DB
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testlp") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

I connected there to my DB

```
// store in the DB 
if(!empty($_POST['ok'])) {  
    // first delete the records marked for deletion. Why? Because we don't want to process them in the code below
    if( !empty($_POST['delete_ids']) and is_array($_POST['delete_ids'])) {

        foreach($_POST['delete_ids'] as $id) {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM recherche WHERE id=$id";
            $link->query($sql);
        }
    }
```

Here normaly I add to my  DB

```
    // adding new recherche
    if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    foreach($_POST['name'] as $name)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO recherche (name) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name)."')";
        $link->query($sql);
    }
} 
}

// select existing recherche here
$sql="SELECT * FROM recherche ORDER BY id";
$result = $link->query($sql);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width:90%;margin:auto;">


    <form method="post">
    <div id="itemRows">

     Item name: <input type="text" name="add_name" /> <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Add row" /> 
     <?php
if($result!=false && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
        <p id="oldRow<?=$product['id']?>"> Item name: <input type="text" name="name<?=$product['id']?>" value="<?=$product['name']?>" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete_ids[]" value="<?=$product['id']?>"> Mark to delete</p>
    <?php endwhile;

}
?>
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="ok" value="Save Changes"></p>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var rowNum = 0;function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    frm.add_qty.value = '';
    frm.add_name.value = '';
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: *"I've a problem my coworker have played in my code and now it's wont work."* --- Next time, work with a copy, so you will have something to revert to.

Comment: does it show any error?

Comment: not any error. when I click on save ubtton my page refresh I double check in my DB and nothing happen. And my code was fin until he play with it. And now for this week he off.

Comment: Here, try this `VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string('$link','$name')."')` at best.

Comment: Also make sure short tags are on. If they are not, do `<?php echo $product['id']?>` instead of `<?=$product['id']?>` which is another possible issue. Changing all `<?=` to `<?php echo`

Comment: this is worst with ('".mysqli_real_escape_string('$link','$name')."') the last part of my code is grey now, when i modify the link and name i have all my page in orange error cause this code you give me is worst.

Comment: You're trying to enter two values but selecting only one column. `$sql = "INSERT INTO recherche (link,name) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string('$link','$name')."')";` if `link` is the other column name. @TheBaconManWithouBacon

Comment: with your last code error : 

`code ! ) Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\wamp\www\testing\dynamic-form-fields.html.php on line 20
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0005 263808 {main}( ) ..\dynamic-form-fields.html.php:0
2 1.0284 273360 mysqli_real_escape_string ( ) ..\dynamic-form-fields.html.php:20
 `.  x4 this error

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. Give me a sec.

Comment: Now this error in the console : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined dynamic-form-fields.html.php:28
addRow dynamic-form-fields.html.php:28
onclick


`code function addRow(frm) {
 rowNum ++;
 var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
 jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
 frm.add_qty.value = '';
 frm.add_name.value = '';
}`

Comment: @Fred-ii- the `$link` in the `mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name)` is his db connection, not a column value -> `string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

Comment: Your submit button is called/named `ok` yet using `if(!empty($_POST['ok'])) {` - Usually we do `if(isset($_POST['ok'])) {` besides that, I couldn't say. This is what happens when trying to figure out someone else's mess. My earlier suggestion wasn't good. I got mixed up with the way it was being inserted as an injection.

Comment: @Sean Yes I know; I've admitted my mistake ;-)

Comment: so my code is damned ? And i can'T fix it and nobody can't?

Answer (score 0):

try it with just a little bit more error handling (and protection from sql injections as a bonus)

```
$link = mysqli_connect(...);
// unlike mysql_connect, mysqli_connect() will not return false when the connection cannot be established
// therefore or die() won't work
if ($link->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

// you have no error handling in your script
// making mysqli throw exceptions makes it harder to miss errors
// you still have to handle them - but at least you will see them now....
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

if(!empty($_POST['ok'])) {  
    // first delete the records marked for deletion. Why? Because we don't want to process them in the code below
    if( !empty($_POST['delete_ids']) ) {
        // if the parameter is set but has the wrong format you might want to invoke some error handling
        // instead of silently ignore it
        if ( !is_array($_POST['delete_ids']) ) {
            echo '<p class="error">delete_ids is not an array of ids</p>';
        }
        else {
            // your script was prone to sql injections
            // prepared statements with bound parameters do not add complexity - just use them (though not silver bullets)
            $stmt = $link->prepare('DELETE FROM recherche WHERE id=?');
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
            foreach($_POST['delete_ids'] as $id) {
                $stmt->execute();   echo '.';
            }
        }
    }

    // adding new recherche
    if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
        if ( !is_array($_POST['name']) ) {
            echo '<p class="error">name is not an array of strings</p>';
        }
        else {
            // your script was prone to sql injections
            // prepared statements with bound parameters do not add complexity - just use them (though not silver bullets)
            $stmt = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO recherche (name) VALUES (?)');
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
            foreach($_POST['name'] as $name) {
            $stmt->execute();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\testing\dynamic-form-fields.html.php on line 38
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0006 266584 {main}( ) ..\dynamic-form-fields.html.php:0

Comment: oops, sorry. try again with `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. This doesn't fix anything - it should just show you what the error is.